# Passing variable's value from controller to another controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have two separate controllers which are `PostController` for returning input value to blade and `APIController` for returning data from the database to blade. I have tried passing the variable with `SESSION` but still no function. Please help.

**Index.blade.php**

```
<form class="form-inline" action="{{ action('PostController@index') }}" method="GET">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 col-form-label">Date : </label>
         <input type="date" name="date" id="date" style="width:160px;" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['submit'])) echo $_GET['date']; else echo date('Y-m-d');?>">
   </div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" value="Inquiry">
</form>
```

**PostController.php**

```
<?php
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
   use Session;

   class PostController extends Controller
   {
      public function index()
      {     
         $getDate = Input::get('date'); //trying to pass this to APIController for query
         $getCurrentDate = date('Y-m-d');

         Session::put('getDate', $getDate); //for example $getDate = '2019-01-01'

         return view('posts.index')->with('getCurrentDate', $getCurrentDate)->with('getDate', $getDate);
      }
   }
```

**APIController.php**

```
<?php    
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
   use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;
   use Session;

   class APIController extends Controller
   {
      public function getQueries()
      {
         ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
         ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

         $getInputDate = Session::get('getDate'); //don't get anything here

         //dd($getInputDate); //have tried dumping, it returns null

         $getCurrentDate = date('Y-m-d');

         if($getInputDate == NULL)
         {
            $query = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date = '$getCurrentDate'");

            return Datatables::of($query)->make(true); 
         }
         else 
         {
            $query = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date = '$getInputDate'");

            return Datatables::of($query)->make(true);
         }
      }
   }
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'PostController@index');  

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    // Put routes in here
    Route::get('/json/getQueries', 'APIController@getQueries')->name('api.posts.index');
});
```

**Api.php**

```
Route::get('/json/getQueries', 'APIController@getQueries')->name('api.posts.index');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    // Put routes in here
    Route::get('/', 'PostController@index'); 
});
```

Comment: which version of laravel are you currently using?

Comment: @RonS Laravel 5.4.

Comment: You can accomplish this using laravel custom-channels.
Documetation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#custom-channels

Comment: @RonS custom channels can pass it even though for separate controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the affected routes within the web middleware group, so you should share the session between them.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    // Put routes in here
});
```

If I'm not mistaken, this case should be for the api routes, which want to share the sessions with the web routes.

Comment: It's working. It must be added in both routes in order to work. I have updated my post

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help you. A cordial greeting.

Answer (score 0):

In controller add use Session; it will work.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#adding-custom-session-drivers

```
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;  
 use Session;
```

I tried the same concept it's working for me.

Comment: I tried it just now. Still not working. I try dd($getInputDate) inside `APIController`, it returns null.

Comment: did you update in both the controller? after update submit the form then check.

Comment: In PostController  what value you are getting of ' $getDate '?

Comment: Date format like this `2019-01-01` but it only will have value when I submit the form. If not submitted yet, then `$getDate` is null. So in `APIController` will check if null, display current date of data. If not null, then display data based on the date submitted.

Comment: I tried your complete code it's working for me :)). Version is 5.4